# jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two DAO Hibernate mapping classes. Relationship is one-to-many bidirectional relationship. When I try to add a new setting I get, the following error.

```
jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, updated_by, updated_time, appType_id) values ('Mxxd', '2015-12-17 11:09:' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1901)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2049)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at com.ips.tvadmindao.services.TvAppTypeService.addAppType(TvAppTypeService.java:53)
    at com.xxx.tvadmindao.services.Application.main(Application.java:50)
2015-12-17 11:09:37 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:144 - SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2015-12-17 11:09:37 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, updated_by, updated_time, appType_id) values ('Kalla', '2015-12-17 11:09:' at line 1
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at com.xxx.tvadmindao.services.TvAppTypeService.addAppType(TvAppTypeService.java:53)
    at com.xxx.tvadmindao.services.Application.main(Application.java:50)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, updated_by, updated_time, appType_id) values ('MenukaD', '2015-12-17 11:09:' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1901)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2049)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 23 more
```

Here with I have added the method that use to add settingstypes.

```
public boolean addAppType() {
        //boolean success = false;
        // add app and setting together
        String appType_name = "AAAA";
        String created_by = "Mxxxd";

        TvAppsType_Settings setting = new TvAppsType_Settings();
        setting.setCreated_by(created_by);
        setting.setCreated_time(new LocalDateTime());
        setting.setKey("Host2");
        setting.setUpdated_by(created_by);
        setting.setUpdated_time(new LocalDateTime());
        TvAppsType apptype2 = (TvAppsType)session.get(TvAppsType.class, 4);

        setting.setApptypes(apptype2);
        session.save(setting);
        if (!HibernateUtil.INSTANCE.commitTransaction())
            return false;
        logger.info("Exited : " + "addAppType(String appType_name, String created_by)");
        return true;
    }
```

There are DAO classes too.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tvapps_type_settings")
public class TvAppsType_Settings {
    @Id  //primary key
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)//strategy for generating auto generated number
    @Column(name = "settingType_id", nullable = false)
    private int  settingType_id;

    /*@Column(name = "appType_id",  insertable=false , updatable=false)
    private int appType_id;*/

    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name= "appType_id",insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private TvAppsType apptypes;

    @Column(name = "key")
    private String key;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    @Column(name = "created_time", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime created_time;

    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false)
    private String created_by;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    @Column(name = "updated_time", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime updated_time;

    @Column(name = "updated_by", nullable = false)
    private String updated_by;

    public TvAppsType getApptypes() {
        return apptypes;
    }

    public void setApptypes(TvAppsType apptypes) {
        this.apptypes = apptypes;
    }

    public int getSettingType_id() {
        return settingType_id;
    }

    public void setSettingType_id(int settingType_id) {
        this.settingType_id = settingType_id;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreated_time() {
        return created_time;
    }

    public void setCreated_time(LocalDateTime created_time) {
        this.created_time = created_time;
    }

    public String getCreated_by() {
        return created_by;
    }

    public void setCreated_by(String created_by) {
        this.created_by = created_by;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdated_time() {
        return updated_time;
    }

    public void setUpdated_time(LocalDateTime updated_time) {
        this.updated_time = updated_time;
    }

    public String getUpdated_by() {
        return updated_by;
    }

    public void setUpdated_by(String updated_by) {
        this.updated_by = updated_by;
    }

}
```

TvAppsType DAO class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tvapps_type")
public class TvAppsType {
    @Id  //primary key
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)//strategy for generating auto generated number
    @Column(name = "appType_id", nullable = false)
    private int appType_id;

    @Column(name = "appType_name", nullable = false)
    private String appType_name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "appType_id",nullable = false)
    private List<TvAppsType_Settings> tvsettings = new ArrayList<TvAppsType_Settings>();

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    @Column(name = "created_time", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime created_time;

    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false)
    private String created_by;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    @Column(name = "updated_time", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime updated_time;

    @Column(name = "updated_by", nullable = false)
    private String updated_by;

    public List<TvAppsType_Settings> getTvsettings() {
        return tvsettings;
    }

    public void setTvsettings(List<TvAppsType_Settings> tvsettings) {
        this.tvsettings = tvsettings;
    }

    public int getAppType_id() {
        return appType_id;
    }

    public void setAppType_id(int appType_id) {
        this.appType_id = appType_id;
    }

    public String getAppType_name() {
        return appType_name;
    }

    public void setAppType_name(String appType_name) {
        this.appType_name = appType_name;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreated_time() {
        return created_time;
    }

    public void setCreated_time(LocalDateTime created_time) {
        this.created_time = created_time;
    }

    public String getCreated_by() {
        return created_by;
    }

    public void setCreated_by(String created_by) {
        this.created_by = created_by;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdated_time() {
        return updated_time;
    }

    public void setUpdated_time(LocalDateTime updated_time) {
        this.updated_time = updated_time;
    }

    public String getUpdated_by() {
        return updated_by;
    }

    public void setUpdated_by(String updated_by) {
        this.updated_by = updated_by;
    }

}
```

Can you guys help me to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySQL-Server doesn't like the fieldname `key`, and your persistence provider doesn't handle that correctly. One option would be to rename the field `key` to something else, if that is possible for you.

Alternatively,

```
@Column(name="`key`")
```

should work.

Comment: Good catch: `KEY` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). It is actually forbidden by standard SQL, according to that linked document.

Answer (score 1):

`key` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. Hibernate doesn't account for it, and pastes your column names as is into the query, hence the error.

There are two ways to fix it. A more sane is to rename your column to be something else, like `setting_key` or something similar.

If you are not OK with renaming it, there's a hacky solution:

```
@Column(name = "`key`")
private String key;
```

Note that the name of the column is now in backticks, and since hibernate just pastes it into the query, it will be interpreted by MySQL as `key`